# Blu-ray transcode to H.265 using Intel Quick Sync Video

Tags: transcoding, playback, h.265

## Blu-ray transcode to [H.265](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding) using [Intel Quick Sync Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video)

I just started a process of transcoding about 100 video discs (with **[DTS-HD Master Audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTS-HD_Master_Audio) on passthrough**) from my collection of Blu-rays and want to store them for backup purposes solely.

---

**Source video codec**: [Advanced Video Codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) at profile High@L4.1.

**Target video codec**: [H.265](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding) using [Intel Quick Sync Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video).

---

Hardware being a new laptop with:

- **CPU**: [Intel Core i7 7700HQ (Kaby Lake)](https://ark.intel.com/products/97185/Intel-Core-i7-7700HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz).
- **GPU**: Intel HD Graphics 630 integrated in the CPU, capable of [Intel Quick Sync Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video) hardware encode of [H.265](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding).

---

I do this with [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/) software version 1.0.7 under Windows 10 Pro.

In short I have applied Constant quality with RF20 and Quality preset for the video.

Originals are all at fixed 7.5 GiB size (it is a series on a Blu-ray Double-layer, so on 1 disc there are 5 episodes).

The sizes of my encodes are usually around 3 GiB +/- 0.5 GiB.

That is about 40 % of the original size overall.

---

## Problem

1. [Media Player Classic - Home Cinema](https://mpc-hc.org/) plays the video using [Native DXVA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX_Video_Acceleration#DXVA2_implementations:_native_and_copy-back) with some unexpected effects, I am unable to describe it, so here's an image in [4K UHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#4K_UHD_(3840%C3%972160)):

   [image: Some unexpected effects while playback in MPC-HC]
2. I own a license for [PowerDVD 17 Ultra](https://www.cyberlink.com/products/powerdvd-ultra/features_en_EU.html), it plays the video just fine, but it does play the video only, not playing the audio at all.
3. Only [VLC Media Player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) plays both video and audio well.

---

## Question

Could anyone point me to the right direction as to if I am doing anything wrong?

Or are these effects of [Intel Quick Sync Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video) *normal*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Wrong container format ([MP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14))

I omitted the information about the container format. I used [MP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) in preliminary tests in an effort to increase compatibility with portable devices.

It did not cross my mind that this would be the cause for the missing audio in [PowerDVD 17 Ultra](https://www.cyberlink.com/products/powerdvd-ultra/features_en_EU.html) player. So the container has been changed to [MKV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska). It did not, however, change anything on the artifacts in [Media Player Classic - Home Cinema](https://mpc-hc.org/).

---

## Probably buggy implementation of [Native DXVA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX_Video_Acceleration#DXVA2_implementations:_native_and_copy-back) in [Media Player Classic - Home Cinema](https://mpc-hc.org/)

Thanks to [Mulvya](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/1871/mulvya), we have found a work-around (not a solution). It seems to be buggy implementation of [Native DXVA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX_Video_Acceleration#DXVA2_implementations:_native_and_copy-back) in [Media Player Classic - Home Cinema](https://mpc-hc.org/). Switching to `Video Mixing Renderer 9 (renderless)` works well.